# CSS: Work with not()

Tags: css

I have a CSS that looks like this:

```
a:focus { background-color: #eeeeee; }
```

Now in CSS3 there's the not() attribute.
How could I work with this when I want add the focus-background-color to all elements
but with one exception: I want that this isn't added to a-tags/elements inside .audio_wrapper

Comment: :not() isn't an attribute, it's a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :not pseudo-class won't help you in this situation because it only accepts [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn), and your condition relies on an attribute of the `a`'s parent. The best solution is just to define the rule and then override it with a second rule for the conditional case.

Edit: On Second thought, you might be able to do it like this:

`:not(.audio_wrapper) a:focus { ...rules... }`

Answer (score 2):

Try with there rules:

```
a:focus { background-color: #eeeeee; }
.audio_wrapper a:focus {background-color: #000000}; <!-- or white or what is your default color-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The not selector is only supported by modern browsers (Firefox, Safari and Opera) and not IE.

a:not(.audio_wrapper){ background-color: #eeeeee; ............}

Comment: That won't work because it excludes `a` elements that do not have a class of "audio_wrapper." In poru's case he wants to exclude `a` elements within a parent element that has a class of "audio_wrapper."